# ElasticSearch apply should and range

Tags: elasticsearch

**My situation:**

I'm working with an ElasticSearch database and I cant apply a couple of "ORs" plus a couple of "ANDs". I'm writing the SQL query to show what I want, in my SQL query I've used `confirmedPlayers` and `pendingPlayers` as they were arrays, of course I know we cant do that in SQL, but I just wanted to take an example.

If you want me to add my mappings, I will, It is just I dont want to make extensive the post.

**This is my query in SQL:**

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM match
 WHERE (
         "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" in confirmedPlayers OR
         "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" in pendingPlayers OR
         "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" = creator
       )
   AND date >= "20/01/2016"
   /* AND other filter will be added */
```

**This is my match type info:**

```json
{
   "took": 79,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 8,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVmak0bWIjogo0aNpbGs",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Mi primer match",
               "date": "2016-01-13T20:31:20.000Z",
               "fromTime": "19:00",
               "toTime": "20:00",
               "location": "casa de pablo",
               "creator": "AVmabq-5Ijogo0aNpbGn",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVm0ETbT0Y26YggShbFa",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Mi primer match",
               "date": "2016-01-13T20:31:20.000Z",
               "fromTime": "19:00",
               "toTime": "20:00",
               "location": "casa de pablo",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVmBKi21XRKVuACJGZZZ",
                  "AVmabq-5Ijogo0aNpbGn"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVmab1G5Ijogo0aNpbGo",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Mi primer match",
               "date": "2016-01-13T20:31:20.000Z",
               "fromTime": "19:00",
               "toTime": "20:00",
               "location": "casa de pablo",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [
                  "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
                  "AVmBKi21XRKVuACJGZZZ"
               ],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVmBKi21XRKVuACJGZZZ"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVm0EPX20Y26YggShbFZ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Mi primer match",
               "date": "2016-01-13T20:31:20.000Z",
               "fromTime": "19:00",
               "toTime": "20:00",
               "location": "casa de pablo",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [
                  "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
                  "AVmabq-5Ijogo0aNpbGn"
               ],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVmBKi21XRKVuACJGZZZ"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "match",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-9fOJxj9yxI50RS3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-ykMJxj9yxI50RS1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-73OJxj9yxI50RS2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This query returns 4 matches, and it is OK.

```json
http://localhost:9200/my_index/match
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            { "term": { "confirmedPlayers": { "value": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" } } },
            { "term": { "pendingPlayers": { "value": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" } } },
            { "term": { "creator": { "value": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O" } } }
         ],
         "must": [
            { "range": { "date": { "gte": "20/01/2016", "format": "dd/MM/yyyy" } } }
         ]
      }
   }
}
//RESULT    
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1.6931472,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "match",
            "_score": 1.6931472,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-73OJxj9yxI50RS2",
            "_score": 1.6931472,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-9fOJxj9yxI50RS3",
            "_score": 1.287682,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-ykMJxj9yxI50RS1",
            "_score": 1.287682,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But this query is returning 4 matches too, and this is the case where it should not return anything.

```json
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            { "term": { "confirmedPlayers": { "value": "inexistant" } } },
            { "term": { "pendingPlayers": { "value": "inexistant" } } },
            { "term": { "creator": { "value": "inexistant" } } }
         ],
         "must": [
            { "range": { "date": { "gte": "20/01/2016", "format": "dd/MM/yyyy" } } }
         ]
      }
   }
}
//RESULT
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "match",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-9fOJxj9yxI50RS3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-ykMJxj9yxI50RS1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "yojuego",
            "_type": "match",
            "_id": "AVnm-73OJxj9yxI50RS2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "otro match 3",
               "date": "2017-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
               "fromTime": "21:00",
               "toTime": "22:00",
               "location": "somewhere",
               "creator": "AVmabVjUIjogo0aNpbGm",
               "matchType": "5",
               "confirmedPlayers": [
                  "AVnJOMvXOX1s7Ny2Wu9O"
               ],
               "pendingPlayers": [],
               "comments": []
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Mappings:**

```json
{
    "match": {
        "properties": {
            "title": { "type": "string" },
            "date": { "type": "date" },
            "fromTime": { "type": "string" },
            "toTime": { "type": "string" },
            "location": { "type": "string" },
            "matchType": { "type": "integer" },
            "creator": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "confirmedPlayers" : {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "pendingPlayers" : {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "comments" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
                    "owner" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "text" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "writtenOn": { "type": "date" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem cames up when I use should and must all togheter. If I use should and must separately they work fine.

Comment: What type of analyzer is used for `confirmedPlayers`, `pendingPlayers`, and  `creator`?

Comment: If those string fields were not set to `index:"not_analyzed"`, then the should clauses would never match because you have capital letters in the search terms.

Comment: I am going to expand my question later. But both filters work fine separately. My problem comes up when I use them all togheter. I will add my mappings too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the result of your second example query (where you claim that 0 results should be returned), it seems you have some confusion about the way that `should` works in elasticsearch.

I'll quote from [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> should
>
> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. ***In a
>   boolean query with no must or filter clauses***, one or more should
>   clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to
>   match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

If you use a query with a `should` and a `must`, it isn't actually necessary that the `should` clause hits, only the `must` clause. If the `should` clauses do happen to hit, they will be ranked higher in the results.

You have options though. One option: you can write a simple `should` query, and set the `minimum_should_match` parameter, then wrap that query in a `filtered` clause to filter based on the date. Second option: create a nested query, with the `must` clause inside the `should` clause.

Comment: The key was in the `minimum_should_match: 1`, just adding it was enough. And yes, I was misunderstanding the way `should` works when it is combined with `must`. Accepted and upvoted, of course.
Thanks.